# GeoServer - How to create source image from directory (JP2) and not only file by file

Tags: geoserver, jpeg-2000

I would like to import all JP2 file from a directory with GeoServer. 
I don't know how to do that. I can create image source with only one file JP2 but not with all file.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution : **Do not use JP2K... but ImageMosaic** because JP2K it's only for display tiles (you can specify only one file) and ImageMosaic is used to display many files from a directory.